# Node js equivalent code for android AES encryption

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt my message in android and decrypt in node js server.

Android Code :

```js
SecretKeySpec secretkeyspec = new SecretKeySpec("password".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkeyspec);
byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encoded));
```

Node JS Code :

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var CIPHER_ALGORITHM = 'aes-128-cbc';
var key = 'password';
var ivBuffer = new Buffer(16);
ivBuffer.fill(0);

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, new Buffer(key, 'utf-8'), ivBuffer);
var encryptedBuffer = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf-8');
var fBuf = new Int8Array(Buffer.concat([encryptedBuffer, cipher.final()]));
console.log(fBuf);
```

When i try to print the buffers im getting different values between android and node js.

Node Buffer :

[26,
   116,
   2,
   -56,
   -70,
   121,
   -44,
   66,
   101,
   84,
   -46,
   127,
   -70,
   -42,
   67,
   31,
   124,
   -104,
   -24,
   88,
   74,
   4,
   -22,
   -70,
   -39,
  48,
 -120,
 -21,
  37,
 -15,
 -24,
 -30 ]

Android Buffer :

[26, 116, 2, -56, -70, 121, -44, 66, 101, 84, -46, 127, -70, -42, 67, 31, -92, 97, 16, -101, -45, -68, 108, 89, -125, 17, -71, 53, 2, -13, 31, -79]

could someone tell whats the android default AES equivalent node js decryption code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

```js
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, new Buffer(key, 'utf-8'), '');
  var encryptedBuffer = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf-8');
  var finalEncryptedBuffer = new Int8Array(Buffer.concat([encryptedBuffer, cipher.final()]));
  console.log(encodeBytes(finalEncryptedBuffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mode of operation (for example, CBC) and padding (for example, PKCS5) are match between both implementations.

Comment: Can't change the android code. But we can change the Node js code. Would be helpful if you tell the equivalent mode and padding. Tried a lot but not able to figure out.